# How to load/edit/run/save text files (.py) into an IPython notebook cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I've recently moved over to using IPython notebooks as part of my workflow.  However, I've not been successful in finding a way to import .py files into the individual cells of an open IPython notebook so that they can edited, run and then saved. Can this be done?

I've found [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/notebook/notebook.html#importing-py-files) in the documentation which tells me how to import .py files as new notebooks but this falls short of what I want to achieve.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good question.  I have yet to see a really satisfying answer.  It's especially important when serving an IPython notebook over the internet.  If people want to see/edit the source code of functions that are imported (with syntax highlighting, etc) there's currently no easy way to do it.  It should be possible to just open py files without transforming them into ipynb files.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

> **EDIT**: Starting from IPython 3 (now Jupyter project), the notebook has a text editor that can be used as a more convenient alternative to
>   load/edit/save text files.

A text file can be loaded in a notebook cell with the magic command `%load`.

If you execute a cell containing:

```
%load filename.py
```

the content of `filename.py` will be loaded in the next cell. You can edit and execute it as usual.

To save the cell content back into a file add the cell-magic `%%writefile filename.py` at the beginning of the cell and run it. Beware that if a file with the same name already exists **it will be silently overwritten**.

To see the help for any magic command add a `?`: like `%load?` or `%%writefile?`.

For general help on magic functions type "%magic"
For a list of the available magic functions, use %lsmagic. For a description
of any of them, type %magic_name?, e.g. '%cd?'.

*See also: [Magic functions](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions) from the official IPython docs.*

Comment: This, plus `%save -f` seems to be the way to do what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `save -f` is a kind of indirect way of saving into a file and will work only if you execute the cell first and then provide the right reference. In general it's easier to use `%%writefile` that writes the current cell into a file. I updated the answer to mention this.

Comment: The new magic command is currently `%loadpy` (instead of `%load`).

Comment: according to https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html using `%load` is fine, going forward: 
"`%loadpy`  ( _Alias of_ `%load` ) --   `%loadpy` has gained some flexibility and dropped the requirement of a `.py` extension. So it has been renamed simply into `%load`. You can look at `%load` docstring for more info."

Comment: Would it be possible to run `%load myfile.py` as a startup parameter for `ipython`?

Answer (score 146):

### To write/save

`%%writefile myfile.py`

- write/save cell contents into myfile.py (use `-a` to append). Another alias: `%%file myfile.py`

### To run

`%run myfile.py`

- run myfile.py and output results in the current cell

### To load/import

`%load myfile.py`

- load "import" myfile.py into the current cell

#### For more magic and help

`%lsmagic`

- list all the other cool cell magic commands.

`%COMMAND-NAME?`

- for help on how to use a certain command. i.e. `%run?`

### Note

Beside the cell magic commands, IPython notebook (now Jupyter notebook) is so cool that it allows you to use any unix command right from the cell (this is also equivalent to using the `%%bash` cell magic command).

To run a unix command from the cell, just precede your command with `!` mark. for example:

- `!python --version` see your python version
- `!python myfile.py` run myfile.py and output results in the current cell, just like `%run` (see the difference between `!python` and `%run` in the comments below).

Also, see [this nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb) for further explanation with examples.

Comment: Aziz, this is an excellent answer.  One small note:  it's very slightly different to use `%run myfile.py` as opposed to `!python myfile.py`.  If you do the former it will execute using the ipython kernel, including whatever preloading is configured.  A small issue, but I ran into a bug today where it made a difference for me.

Comment: If you want to do the equivalent of `%run myfile.py` described in this answer while including IPython cell magic commands in your script, use `%run myfile.ipy`.

Answer (score 9):

Drag and drop a Python file in the Ipython notebooks "home" notebooks table, click upload. This will create a new notebook with only one cell containing your .py file content

Else copy/paste from your favorite editor ;)

Answer (score 5):

I have found it satisfactory to use ls and cd within ipython notebook to find the file. Then type cat your_file_name into the cell, and you'll get back the contents of the file, which you can then paste into the cell as code.

Comment: `!cat "file.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a satisfying answer for this question, i.e how to load edit, run and save. Overwriting either using `%%writefile` or `%save -f` doesn't work well if you want to show incremental changes in git. It would look like you delete all the lines in `filename.py` and add all new lines, even though you just edit 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

to write in a file that exists or not use the following

```
%%writefile script2.py
print(4+5) 
print(5+5)
```

to append to a file use -a argument

```
%%writefile -a script2.py
print("hello")
```

when you load the file

```
%load script2.py
print(4+5)
print(5+5
print("hello")
```