# Loading python script in ipython as ipython cells

Tags: python, ipython

We can use %run to execute a python script inside ipython console (not notebook). However, is there a way we can run the script and have each line of script load and execute as one cell of ipython input. For e.g. if the script is:

```
if a == b:
  print 2*a

if a == 2*b:
  print a
```

Then inside of ipython the script must load (and execute) like so:

```
In [1]: if a == b:
   ...:     print 2*a
   ...:

In [2]: if a == 2*b:
   ...:     print a
   ...:
```

I don't know if this is even possible, but if so, it will be really helpful as I can load the script and then execute whichever portion of code that I want to execute. A follow up question would be whether we can load the source code of an imported module recursively (like stepping inside a debugger). That way we can make develop and test from within ipython itself, without executing the entire code from scratch (since ipython saves state per cell).

Comment: If using iPython/Jupyter notebook you can copy+paste whole/partial scripts into the cells and run in whatever order you like.  My $0.02: I typically develop in iPython cell's then move to standalone scripts once the code is proven to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out following thing,

`!python filename.py`

There is another option also, you can copy paste your code into ipython using 
%cpaste and at the end ctrl+d to exit from 
`%cpaste`

`%edit`
in ipython allows to type code, and saved in `/tmp/ipython_edit_3xhsby0h/ipython_edit_*.py` after exiting from the edit mode it executes the list of lines written in above file use `:q` to quit from the edit mode

And to go in debug mode you can try out this 

`python -m pdb filename.py`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034373/how-to-load-edit-run-save-text-files-py-into-an-ipython-notebook-cell) provides an answer. To summarize, you want to use the magic command `%load`.

If you execute a cell containing:

```
%load filename.py
```

the content of `filename.py` will be loaded in the next cell. You can edit and execute it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Go to script, `ctrl`+`A` then `ctrl`+`c`, go to terminal,type `%paste`
Script is pasted and run