# what does '%%file test.py' mean in python?

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

Just as the title said. I'm trying to figure out what does the '%%' mean. It seems to be not a Placeholder here?

```
%%file test_theano.py
from theano import config
print 'using device:', config.device
```

Comment: `%%file` is an alias for the `%%writefile` cell magic in ipython, which writes the contents of this cell to the file specified. See: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That `%%file` command is not Python, but rather an IPython "magic" command.  It puts the content which follows into a file named by its parameter.

Some time ago it was renamed `%%writefile`, but the old name is still supported, though no longer documented.  You can find the documentation for `%%writefile` here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html

If you try it in an IPython shell it will be quite clear what it does - it creates a file called `test_theano.py` in the current directory.

See also: [How to load/edit/run/save text files (.py) into an IPython notebook cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034373/how-to-load-edit-run-save-text-files-py-into-an-ipython-notebook-cell)

Comment: Thanks @John Zwinck you are correct about it. I just realized it when I try it in an IPython notebook and get a file named test_theano.py.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an example to support what John wrote.

Run this in Ipython (or some Ipython shell such as Jupyter):

```
%%file test.py

some_list=[1,2,3]
```

The program will return

> Writing test.py

IPython created a test.py file in the imediate environment.
Open the test.py and you would see:

```
 some_list=[1,2,3]
```