# converting files to and from .ipynb and .py

Tags: python, file-conversion

I have a .py file with code blocks separated in cells by `#%%` for example

```
#%%
block1
#%%
block2
```

This appears to be quite similar to ipynb cells; is there a quick way to convert such a python file to and from ipynb (while preserving the cells format)?

Comment: Would this thread help your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034906/9814037 ?

Comment: i want a mapping between python's cell to ipynb cell, that link gives option to load a file as a cell in ipynb

Comment: Maybe a bit unrelated, but you might be interested on having a look on [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)

Comment: As far as I recall, I have not seen such a thing in a package management (apt/brew). As a result, I suppose you should create something open source on GitHub.